# How does mobaXterm know whether x11 forwarding is working on remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, forwarding

When using SSH mode to connect to some linux servers:

For some servers, mobaxterm shows "X11-forwarding  : ✔  (remote display is forwarded through SSH)" and I can start some gui application in local windows.

For some servers, mobaxterm shows "X11-forwarding  : ✘  (disabled or not supported by server)

My question is, how does mobaxterm know this information? On both servers I've configured /etc/ssh/ssh_config to have:

> X11Forwarding yes
>
> ForwardX11 yes

I'm not sure which config line really works so I had both. Question is, how does mobaxterm know, is it part of ssh communication to tell, whether the linux server supports ssh forwarding or not?

Comment: Not familiar with MobaXterm, but it probably simply checks whether the X11 port is set and listening.

Comment: Having the same problem with MobaXTerm accessing -- what seems to me by close inspection of /etc/ssh/ssh_config -- identically configured Ubuntu 14.04 boxes.  MobaXTerm says one server supports X11Forwarding, the other one, not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having a similar problem: MobaXterm was saying one of my servers DID support X11 forwarding, and the other didn't.  This was maddening, as the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` files were identical.  My problem was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/860957/292710).

Seems you are looking in the wrong place, like I was.

- The file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` configures SSH *clients* on your host.
- The file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configures the SSH *server* on your host.

Thus, check for the line "X11Forwarding" in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  (Note the "d".)  If uncommented and set to "yes", then X11 forwarding *should* work... and I bet MobaXterm will detect this.

Answer (score 26):

1. Ensure `xorg-x11-xauth` is installed
2. /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
# AddressFamily any
AddressFamily inet

AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218584

Comment: RHEL 7.4 - apparently this is not installed naturally...

Comment: `apt install xauth`for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, xauth might be in different locations depending on the OS release (/usr/bin or /usr/openwin/bin).

So it is also worth verifying that the parameter XAuthLocation is correctly set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

HTH,
Stefane

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the solution described here https://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami especially:

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-utils.x86_64 dbus-x11.x86_64
```